# Access to another maven dependency configuration files

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing here because I'm getting headaches trying to find out what is happening.

I'm currently working on a "toolbox" project where the id is to validate a provided string among different kind of rules.
I've stored the different rules on XML files and the project itself works properly.

Its structure is something like :

```
ValidatorProject :
|___ src/main/java
|____ ValidatorManage.java (this one have a method that is able to load the correct config validator file and validate the provided String)
|___ src/main/resources
|____ *.xml (a lot of xml config files)
```

Unit testing, direct Manager instanciation inside the project itself works as expected.

Now I'd like to add this project as a maven dependency to other projects that could need to validate some datas.

My problem as creating a new ValidatorManger instance in the second project `ValidatorManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` is not working because it used the project n°2 classpath and can't find the config files.

I tried to import the resources in the maven build of the validator project (I got it if I unzip the jar file), but I don't know how can I have access to it.

If someone have the solution (and more important the explanations about the way it work) I would be really grateful for it cause I turn around on this.
I'm pretty sure there is something to do during the maven build of the validator project but can't find what.

Thanks in advance for taking time to read me and sorry for my english :/

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml config files under src/main/resources

Comment: Hello, there are already under the src/main/resources (I've edited my message cause I might make a mistake while typing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find something working;

I'm not sure this is the way to do it (also do not seem to be really practical to do that for every project that need this project);

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/examples/sharing-resources.html

At least this is working for now, I'm still open for better solution if you have some.